# Can I use Shift, Alt and Control Modifier Keys Together With the Function Keys on the Touch Bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

I've configured my touch bar to always show function keys in one program where I use those frequently (IntelliJ IDEA, code editor). Many hotkeys in IDEA are triggered using a function key together with shift, alt or control, e.g. for renaming a variable, I use Shift+F6.

With the emulated function keys, this does not work, the program acts as if I had just hit F6 without holding down the alt key.

It was no problem with the hardware function keys on my old MacBook.

Is this a known bug, or a limitation one has to live with? Or is there some way to work around it? Perhaps I'm just to stupid and missing something obvious?

This is a major pain for me as a software developer…

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @Patrick mentions in his answer, one cause of this problem is [Karabiner-Elements](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html) not enabling the Touch Bar "keyboard" by default. The solution is to enable that keyboard in Karabiner-Elements Preferences (Vendor ID 1452, Product ID 34304) as shown in following screenshot:

[image]

I filed [Touch Bar keyboard should be enabled by default · Issue #1700 · tekezo/Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1700) to request it be enabled by default in Karabiner-Elements.

More information in the following comments:

- https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/535#issuecomment-350522019
- https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/535#issuecomment-350597725

Comment: In addition to this, I had to select "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" under the "Function Keys" section. Now I can debug again! :)

Comment: I had to also tweak Function Keys mappings. I'm using "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" = on for all devices and had to map f1 -> f1, etc. for the Touch Bar device.

Answer (score 9):

Ah, after some digging, I found out it's the fault of Karabiner Elements, a utility program I'm using to reassign some keys.

https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/435

Answer (score 0):

To make function keys work as normal i Android Studio - apart from enabling keyboard: "No product name"  I had to go into Preferences -> Function keys and DISABLE the option: "Use all F1, F2.... as standard function keys"....

[image]